# How can I play a sound at regular intervals?

Tags: java, audio, codenameone

Here is some code that is **successfully being called about twice a second**. The sound file is about 100ms long. It only plays once, but I expected this to keep playing it: the subsequent calls step over the `play` call without an exception thrown, but also without a sound.

Is there an efficient way of making it work?

```
        InputStream knockAudio = fetchResourceFile().getData("mysound.wav");
        try {
            final Media m = MediaManager.createMedia(knockAudio, "audio/wav");

            onClickTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.cleanup(); // Here's something I tried, but had no effect
                    m.prepare(); // I also tried this without cleanup
                    m.play(); // But to start with just had this (no cleanup or prepare)
                }
            };

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Shai Almog for the information. This has led me to implement it thus:

Initialize like this:

```
InputStream myAudio = fetchResourceFile().getData("mysound.wav");
```

To repeat-play I do this:

```
myAudio.reset(); // The input stream needs to go back to the beginning
myClip = MediaManager.createMedia(myAudio, "audio/wav");
myClip.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sound on Codename One is cleared/deleted automatically after the first play. You have to re-create it which isn't as expensive as it sounds.

The reason for this is related to the most common bugs in media playback which is lack of proper cleanup so we implicitly do that to avoid such memory leaks. Since the input stream you are fetching is created in RAM the overhead for this should be relatively low.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to schedule the task using a `Timer`:

```
        onClickTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                m.play(); // But to start with just had this (no cleanup or prepare)
            }
        };

        Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(onClickTask, 0, 2000);
```

Comment: I've tried to be clearer in the question - I am calling the task from a timer, but the sound won't play a second time.